# How to edit the text of a message send by my telegram bot with node-telegram-bot-api?

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I am currently using Telegram as a tool to start & watch/log a script with the node-telegram-bot-api.
The idea is to have a text with 'Uploaded Files: 1/10' and then will be edited according to the status of the upload in the backend.

```
bot.sendMessage(telegramChatID, 'Uploaded Files: 1/10', {
    'disable_notification': true
});
```

But how do I get the message_id of the text sent by the bot so I can edit it later on?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

It should work for you:

```
bot.sendMessage(telegramChatID, 'Uploaded Files: 1/10', {
    'disable_notification': true
}).then((msg)=>{
    console.log(msg.message_id); // <-- Here you can save id to update message later
});
```